# How to find v through superposition theorem in the following ciruit

Tags: circuit-design, short-circuit, homework, superposition

What is the voltage V of the attached circuit? Using super position theorem. When i active the 9V source & short 12 V source is the current follows in 20 ohms, 10 ohms. & 4 ohms? Or it only flows to 4 ohms?
[image: What is the voltage V of the attached circuit? Using super position theorem]

Comment: Welcome Tatiana, but this is a homework problem. Be aware that EE.SE is not a homework answering service, and we are not here to do your work for you. If you do not show any attempt to solve the question, your question will more than likely not be received well, attract downvotes, and probably be closed. (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info)

Comment: @EdgarBrown You're right about what you said. However, I believe Tatiana is asking for a particular concept. She's not asking for an answer here but rather if she's doing something right in order to solve for her solution. When she asked for the voltage across the 20 ohm resistor, I believe she's letting us know that this is her objective and then she provides some uncertainties.

Comment: Why would it not flow through the 20 and 10 resistors? Does a circuit remain that includes them?

Comment: Hint: I don't see the need for superposition theorem here. You're overcomplicating things. Just neglect the right hand side of the 9V supply and write down KCL at the top leftmost node. To make life easier put the ground at the +ve terminal of the 9V battery and do the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.
[image]
Ideal resistance (0Ω) of 20V voltage source shorts out 15Ω resistor.

Ideal resistance (∞Ω) of 3A current source opens 6Ω branch.

This leaves 10Ω and 20Ω in series in parallel with 4Ω.

Comment: If 12v source active & 9V source shorted then? Is is it shorted out the complete left side of the circuit?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 0):

The 9V source keeps 9V, 12V source and other parts in the right side of the 9V source cannot affect voltage v. The resulted v would be the same if you cut those parts totally off.

Assuming the order was "use superposition" you shoud calculate only v1 when 9V is changed to 0V (=a wire instead of voltage source) and V2 when the 3A current source (and 6 Ohm resistor) is taken off. The final v=V1+V2